# Species specific White Blood Cells (WBC) composition

Tags: evolution, cell-biology, immunology, pathology

In our ongoing immunology undergrad course I learnt that neutrophil primarily fights off bacterial infection and lymphocyte is produced in response to viral infection. I also learnt that neutrophil count in humans is about 70 % in human WBCs while in horse lymphocytes account for 68% of WBC. It is supposed to make humans more immune to bacterial infection and similarly horses better adapted to fight off viral infections. However I cannot find out any relevant material as to what could be the reason that such biased WBC cell component composition has evolved in different species. Please help me find out relevant material on this.

Comment: World Boxing Council? Please do not use abbreviations in titles and define them the first time you use them.

Comment: Sorry about that.